# What did Damon regret not telling Cee?

Tags: prospect

Near the beginning of *Prospect*, while Cee's father is falling asleep he says:

> *I'm sorry I didn't tell you. I should have told you.*

There were in fact two things which he hadn't told her before today: that the line was shutting down, and that she was born on Lao and not Camria.

But she immediately asks him *"Tell me what?"* which suggests to the viewer that there was something else Damon hadn't told her.  (Or perhaps it simply tells us that her father only feels guilty about one of the "secrets" but she doesn't know which one.)

Is there anything in the rest of the film, or from outside the film, that reveals what he regretted having failed to tell her?